# Почему не загружается картинка?

Tags: html, img

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Изображение</title>
</head>
<body>
<p><img src="http://www.astronews.ru/cgi-bin/mng.cgi?page=astrofoto&id=806" width="100%"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: <img src="http://www.astronews.ru/foto/b/806.jpg" > ?

Comment: все равно не получается

Comment: http:// добавь к www.astronews.ru/foto/b/806.jpg

Answer (score 2):

Ссылка *`http://www.astronews.ru/cgi-bin/mng.cgi?page=astrofoto&id=806`* -
 указывает на страницу с картинкой а не на саму картинку.

Скопируйте ссылку нажав ПКМ на картинке, далее выберите пункт "Копировать URL картинки" и вставьте полученную ссылку в атрибут SRC="".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Изображение</title>
</head>
<body>
<p><img src="http://www.astronews.ru/foto/b/806.jpg" width="100%"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Картинка не загружается, потому по этому адресу (http://www.astronews.ru/cgi-bin/mng.cgi?page=astrofoto&id=806) открывается HTML страница, а не картинка.